# Creating numpy array with different steps

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sequence

I would like to create an array like the following:

```
# 0 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32
```

In which, each element except the first, is the double of the previous one.
I can create this smaller through an iteration and so on.

However, as Python provides a lot of one-liner functions, I was wondering if there is one that allows me to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could be one line, but this is more explicit:

```
x = np.multiply.accumulate( np.ones( 10 )*2)
x[0] = 0
```

OR

```
x  = 2**np.arange(1,10)
x[0] = 0
```

Comment: I like the use of `arange` and exponentiation, makes it clear what's happening.

Comment: Or more compactly: `np.cumprod(np.full((5,),2))`

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
```

You could use a list comprehension to evaluate your power function (`2^n` in this case), then generate a `numpy.array` from that.

```
>>> np.array([0] + [2**i for i in range(2, 10)])
array([  0,   4,   8,  16,  32,  64, 128, 256, 512])
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.logspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html) to get log-spaced ranges. Use the `base=N` keyword argument to set the base of the exponent:

```
In [27]: np.logspace(0, 10, 11, base=2).astype(int)
Out[27]: array([   1,    2,    4,    8,   16,   32,   64,  128,  256,  512, 1024])
```

I like this method because the "logspace" function name makes it clear that I'm going for a range with log (as opposed to linear) spacing.